# Radio-button checked not registered with change()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button

I know this is a common question and I understand why it isn't working. Problem is that the suggested answers are not working for me.

HTML code:

```
<label class="radio"><img id="boyImg" class="radio-img btn-boy" src="/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/boy.png"><input type="radio" name="Gender" value="Boy"></label>
<label class="radio"><img id="girlImg" class="radio-img btn-girl" src="/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/girl.png"><input type="radio" name="Gender" value="Girl"></label>
```

I have the following code:

```
$('input[type=radio]').on('change', function() {
    $(this).closest("form").submit();
});
```

Which is working as expected the first time. Problem is that when I navigate back to the page with the radio button. It only works if I select a different radio buttons - selecting the same isn't working. Despite none of them are selected, when coming back to the page. In other words, I can't select e.g. Boy twice in a row, despite having navigate to another page in between my selections.

I've tried the following fix:

```
$('input[type=radio]').on('change', function() {
   if($('input[value="Boy"]').is(':checked') || $('input[value="Girl"]').is(':checked')){
        $(this).closest("form").submit();
   }
});
```

But it still only works if I select a different checkbox than my original choice.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround, you can use `click` event. It has something to do probably with browser autocomplete. Try different browser.

Comment: Replicated the issue in both Chrome, FF and Safari. You suggestion with using click fixed it. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

That's an odd browser quirk that the selected radio button is stored but not displayed as selected. Simplest workaround for your purposes would be adding click.

```
$('input[type=radio]').on('change,click', function() {
$(this).closest("form").submit();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Dean - I accepted MartinP as the answer, as he also mentioned the click, which solved it. Appreciate you providing the code for others who have the same issue. Cheers!